# How to make input box work in the result page

Tags: django, search-box

I am learning Django and i learn on making small project for lEARNING PURPOSE.

I learned how work with input and use as variable. Now i want to use search box with the same principle.

Please see the link of input based :

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58813945/changing-form-to-search-box
```

`index.html` is the input after inserting info and clicking ok it directs to `index2.html` which shows the results 
What I need to change besides POST to GET to make it work as it works with input function? do i need to change form, models?

My concern also i want to inset search bar in the navigation in `index2.html` where user can make search from the result page.  This is my `index2.html` page. I tried to put `{{form.as_p }}` inside the form function but it does not work. I want after putting infro in search box and clicking search glyphicon (which does not work) will stay on the same page `index2.html`

I searched the internet and read stackoverflow other examples, but they use complicated version, i need a simple one :
1. i want to have search box on `index.html` page so it does not show me the name in front of input box and 
2. i want search box in the index2.html page keep implementing the same function as index.html so a user do not have to go the initial page to search new data.

Any help or tips would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Django is simple, and there are plenty of tutorials, Please browse those and ask for any difficulties that you face while following those tutorials in Stack Overflow

Comment: i took class beofre staring to make mini project )))

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using bootstrap4 I would recommend to use its [template tags](https://django-bootstrap4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/templatetags.html) and form field customization options.

Example:

`{% bootstrap_field form.login show_label=False addon_before='<span class="fa fa-user"></span>' %}`

Not: this example uses [Font Aweseome](https://fontawesome.bootstrapcheatsheets.com/) for icons.

Also you're not using the real power of Django Bootstrap4, see [Quickstart](https://django-bootstrap4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html). You can always override the version of Booststrap or the CDN used in your `settings.py` if needed: [Settings](https://django-bootstrap4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/settings.html).

Comment: Thank you, but i do not understand how this related to my question.......